# How to remove a white space on top of CSS block

Tags: html, css, next.js

I'm making some adaptations to my website to make it responsive and work well on mobile. However, when reducing the width of the page, a white space appears above my first element with `position: relative` (the first is the navigation bar, with absolute position).

I've already tried leaving the margin-top, margin and padding as 0 on all div elements in that part. I also tried eliminating all other blocks on the site to see if it could be a limitation of another unrelated snippet. I visited the other topics with this white space (usually at the end or on the right side of the page) but at first I couldn't solve the problem.

Tried to remove all `position: relative` and insert `overflow: hidden` but didn't work. Global CSS also has `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` and the space doesn't seem to be from those (image below of inspect of main wrapper)

[image: Main wrapper on Opera]

Here goes an example of the white space

[image: Example of white space]

And what it should be

[image: Website without white space]

Here are the CSS and HTML/js codes

**Cover.module.css**

```
.cover {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 8vh 10px 0 4vw;
    position: relative;
    color: #F0F0F0;
}

.wrap {
    height: max(45vw,50vh);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #010F3D;
    margin-top: 10vh;
}

.bg {
    opacity: 0.05;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.fakeBtn {
    background-color: #610770;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 11vh;
    padding: 1%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: max(2.6vw,18px);
}

.horizontalSplit {
    display: flex;
}

.secondColumn{
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.firstColumn {
    width: 70%;
}

.verticalAlign {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.line {
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

.subtitle {
    padding-right: 2vw;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 10vw;
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrap {
        margin: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        height: 45vh;
    }
    .cover {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .firstColumn {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .secondColumn{
        width: 0;
    }

    .subtitle {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .bg {
        height: 50vh;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

**Cover.js** (i'm using NextJS)

```
import styles from '../../styles/Cover.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image';

export default () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.wrap}>
            <img className={styles.bg} src='/Back_Cover.png' alt=""/>
            <div className={styles.cover}>
                {/** Div com as duas colunas, com altura "100" vh */}
                <div className={[styles.horizontalSplit].join(" ")}>
                    {/** Primeira coluna, 100vh */}
                    <div className={[styles.firstColumn].join(" ")}>
                        {/** 1a linha, para o título, contendo 2 colunas */}
                        <div className={[styles.horizontalSplit, styles.line, styles.verticalAlign].join(" ")}>
                            {/** Controle esquerdo */}
                            <div style={{width: "13%", minWidth: "32px"}}> 
                                <Image src='/Controle_L.png' layout="responsive" width={480} height={1024} />
                            </div>
                            {/** Título */}
                            <div style={{paddingLeft: "2vw"}}>
                                <h1>Conectamos talentos a indústria de games</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/** 2a linha, para o subtítulo, contendo 2 colunas */}
                        <div className={[styles.horizontalSplit, styles.line, styles.verticalAlign].join(" ")}>
                            {/** Subtítulo */}
                            <div className={styles.subtitle}>
                                <h2>Buscamos de forma personalizada o profissional perfeito para alavancar o projeto do seu game</h2>
                            </div>
                            {/** Controle direito */}
                            <div style={{width: "15%", minWidth: "30px"}}>
                                <Image src='/Controle_R.png'  layout="responsive" width={480} height={1024}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/** 4a linha, para o call to action */}
                        <div className={styles.line}>
                            {/** Fake button */}
                            <a href='' target="_blank">
                                <div className={[styles.fakeBtn, styles.verticalAlign, styles.secondColumn].join(" ")} style={{justifyContent:"center"}} >
                                    Entre em contato
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    {/** Segunda coluna com apenas o tamanho da figura */}
                    <div className={[styles.secondColumn].join(" ")}>
                        <Image src='/Right_Cover.png' width={250} height={250}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**global.css**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  font-size: max(1.3vw,15px);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
  body {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: max(5vw,35px);
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: max(2.5vw,18px);
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: max(2vw,18px);
  margin: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
}

p{
  line-height: max(2vw,15px);
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Without one, your chances of getting help are slim as the code you shared is neither runnable, nor complete (importing it into a next.js setup does not guarantee the same result, since you're only sharing a fraction of your project). Note codesandbox allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) local projects via cli.

Comment: On a separate note, this looks like a vertical alignment/centering issue. You should be able to fix it by either: *a)* removing the white background from the parent; *b)* changing the alignment of the centered child on the appropriate direction from `center` to `start`. Without a runnable example I can't help more.